# Drawing objects in Direct3D 11 that have varying number of primitives

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11

this is my first question, so if you have any suggestions on how to improve the question, feel free to tell me :)

So my problem is this: I have an object that changes each frame, and this results in a varying number of vertices that I plan to send through my pipeline. Now, I obviously can't change the size of my vertex buffer on the fly, so what is the best way to approach this?

Here are some of the ideas I had:

1. Make a vertex buffer of size *n*, and simply pass the vertices in bunches of *n*. Downsides: some vertices go through the VS multiple times, so a small decrease in performance (probably not noticeable), having to call Map/Unmap several times per frame, which could be problematic.
2. Make a huge vertex buffer that will hold enough vertices that my object will never exceed the size of the buffer. Downsides: since I don't know in advance how many vertices my object will have, it might be hard to predict the size of this buffer. In addition, the buffer might take up too much space as a result.
3. Each frame, create a new vertex buffer of the correct size, and call IASetVertexBuffer. Downsides: This will probably have a huge performance issue...

I'd appreciate any ideas your guys have, or suggestions on which one of these three to use! :)

Comment: What kind of vertex data are you sending down?  #2 would generally be a good choice but I'm surprised you're concerned about its size. Even the most detailed objects usually have well under 100K verts, and even with a generous vertex size of 8 float4s, you're still only talking about a 13MB buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/This is not ideal, since as you said you need to map/unmap several times, and do draw calls in between. You do a trade off to lose performance for less memory usage, on a modern card (count in gigabytes of data), memory is unlikely to be an issue (as mentioned in comment).

2/As opposite of 1, you need a single Map/Unmap, and a single draw (you can also specify vertices count in DeviceContext->Draw to make sure you only draw relevant part of your buffer). This will be your best choice performance wise, and it should not be too hard to have some form of maximum defined (even 1 million poly is not so much memory, and you'll have quite a hard time to have your CPU feeding that amount of data every frame).

3/I don't see any good benefit in your use case (recreating resources is common when you do async load for some immutable resources, so it doesn't really apply here).

So go for 2, if one day memory becomes an issue it's quite easy to move back to 1, but I doubt this will ever happen.

Comment: Thanks. Along the same lines, it would probably be better to concatenate a bunch of vertex buffers CPU-side, then call a single Map/Unmap and Draw (compared to Map/Unmapping for each object)?